# Netty MessageToByteEncoder vs direct push via Unpooled.wrappedBuffer

Tags: java, network-programming, netty, nio

I have an C++ client connect to my Java netty server using TCP and I met this issue when I try to pre-pend the message length to the message and send to the C++ client:

I extended the MessageToByteEncoder and encode it as below

```
int length = msg.getLength();    
byte[] data = msg.getData();
short littleEndianLength = ByteBufUtil.swapShort(length);
out.writeShort(littleEndianLength);
out.writeBytes(data, 0, length);
```

Then send the message using this method (in the handler)

```
channel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(sendListener);
```

BUT, the client does not receive the message.

I change to alternative way, I create the binary message directly and send like below:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[msgLength + 2];
// Convert message length to little-endian byte order
buf[0] = (byte) (msgLength & 0xFF);
buf[1] = (byte) ((msgLength >> 8) & 0xFF);

System.arraycopy(data, 0, buf, 2, msgLength);
ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(buf);
channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf).addListener(sendListener);
```

The client RECEIVES the message.

Can someone help me explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `MessageToByteEncoder` and your encoder expects a certain type of message, which doesn't seem to be a `ByteBuf` looking from your code, you have to write that type of message instead of a `ByteBuf`.  Otherwise, `MessageToByteEncoder` will not handle the `ByteBuf` and just pass it to the next handler in the pipeline.

Therefore, you should do the following instead of writing `byteBuf`:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(sendListener);
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, my example exactly same with your correction, but it's still not working. In fact, my application have 2 bootstraps listening 2 ports, 1 bootstrap using the second example, it works, the other bootstrap using the first example, it works. I am really confusing how the netty channel pipeline working.